# Double cone on two intersecting rails

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

[image]
In the above image is a physics problem which has a horizontal double cone rolling on two intersecting rails. The answer to the question is that the cone would go towards left, but I'm not able to visualise the situation. I would be highly grateful if you could make a simulation of this.

Comment: If the question here is, which way would it turn, this isn't the right place for that kind of question; what things do in Blender simulations often has nothing to do with what happens in reality.  But otherwise, I can't tell what the question is-- it just looks like a work request.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

On the left, the situation you describe.

On the right, another way to see it: the left part of the double cone is smaller.

On the situation where the rails are not symetrical, the left part rolls onto a progressivly smaller section of it (as if it was a smaller cone).

So for one turn, the travelled section of the right cone is greater than the one on the left. So it turns to the left.

A blend file with the rigid body setting (rails are passive, the cones are active with their geometry set to mesh).

[image]